# Teradata SQL returning previous two months, based on CURRENT_DATE

Tags: sql, performance, date, teradata

**TLDR:**
I want to get a table with the previous two months in Teradata, based on CURRENT_DATE. Currently I can only get the previous month:

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -1), 'YYYY-MM') MM;
```

[image: is]

Expected output is:

```
+--------+
|   MM   |
+--------+
| 2020-01|
| 2019-12|
+--------+
```

---

**Long version:**
I want something, that could be used in a bigger query like this, valid for every day of the year, without hardcoding the dates. The bigger query with the hardcoded dates looks like this:

```
AND TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') IN ('2020-01', '2019-12')
```

and it works perfectly. The below one returns results ok, but only for 1 month.

```
AND TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') IN 
(
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -1), 'YYYY-MM')
)
```

Tried to add a comma and add the same line with `-2`, **did not work**:

```
AND TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') IN 
(
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -1), 'YYYY-MM'),
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -2), 'YYYY-MM')
)
```

the error is:

> SELECT Failed 3706: Syntax error: expected something between ')' and '.'.

Comment: Based on the deleted answer/comments: is it a simple union you want, two rows with 2020-01 and 2019-02 as values?

Comment: @Turo - Actually, I want something, that could be used in a bigger query like this: 
 `AND SOME_DATE IN ('2020-01', '2019-12')`, without hardcoding the dates.

Comment: UNION would to the trick, but whats wrong with between?

Comment: @Turo - I guess nothing is wrong with both of them, if they can provide the needed answer, without hardcoding.

Comment: Teradata doesn't allow calculated expressions in `IN` (for a single condition it's probably converted to `=`) , don't know why this stupid restriction exists.

Comment: @dnoeth - this is something I also thought of, but was not sure. Anyway, they really should have a good security reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an or

```
select * from table where 
   (SOME_DATE =  To_char(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE , -2),'YYYY-MM') OR 
   SOME_DATE =  To_char(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE , -1),'YYYY-MM'))
```

Comment: `SOME_DATE` is a char, thus it should match these two.

Comment: then its an or.

Comment: Hm... This would probably work, but `SOME_DATE` is calculated twice and would slow it down. Take a look at the updated question, I have added more info.

Comment: so there is no valid value in between and the previuos answer would have worked. But what you reale want ist to check if the date is i.e. between 2019-12-01(first of preprevious month) and 2020-01-31(last of previous month), rigtht?

Comment: Well, currently the query runs perfectly like this: `AND TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') IN ('2020-01', '2019-12')` and the only thing I want is to replace the `('2020-01', '2019-12')` with calculated values and not hardcoded ones. I do not want to change the structure of the query.

Comment: It's the wrong way, since your formatting the date for every row without needing it, but here you find the workaround for the missing tables in the union. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901803/what-is-teradatas-equivalent-for-oracles-dual

Comment: Actually if I have to replace the `1` in the query of the link with the whole `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(...`, I better go with the `OR` from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation is too compliated:

```
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -1), 'YYYY-MM')
= To_Char(Add_Months(Current_Date, -1), 'YYYY-MM')

TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE  - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE )+1, -2), 'YYYY-MM')
= To_Char(Add_Months(Current_Date, -2), 'YYYY-MM')
```

But your approach to compare YYYY_MM is totally wrong.

Assumimg `SOME_DATE` is actually a DATE CASTing it to a string results in loosing statistics and a Full Table Scan if the table is partition by that date. Both can possibly lead to a bad plan.

You should keep the date column as-is and do all calculation on CURRENT_DATE:

```
WHERE som_date BETWEEN Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date, -2), 'mon')
                   AND Current_Date - Extract(DAY From Current_Date)
```

Comment: `AND Last_Day(Current_Date)` would give the current month, I want "previous" and "previous previous". But the idea is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something with sub query:

```
select * from table where date in 
(SELECT To_char(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE , -2),'YYYY-MM') MM
union 
SELECT To_char(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE , -1),'YYYY-MM') MM
);
```

Comment: I have changed the `IN` part of my big query, but it gave me an error, `3888 - A SELECT for UNION, INTERSECT or MINUS must reference a table.`

Comment: RIght, for these cases ther is SYSDUMMY in DB2, dual in Orcale, but Teradata i don't know

Comment: for teradta there is no dummy table. Simply select 1;  will give you 1. Select 1 where 1= 1; will also give you result.